# C# find all Latitude and Longitude within a mile

Tags: c#, geocoding, latitude-longitude

Given a lat and long value, is there any way of finding all lat and longs that are within a specified distance? I have a db table of lat and long values which are locations of let's say street lamps, given a lat long pair how could I find all those that are within a particular distance?

I guess drawing a circle from the starting point and finding all lat and longs contained would be the best way however, I don't have the skills to do this. I am a c# developer by trade but need a few pointers in the whole geocoding world.

Comment: Latitude and longitude are continuous values, you can't just find all of them in some area, there is infinite number of them.

Comment: You don't say it specifically, but I assume you have a list of lat/lon points?  Otherwise, there are an infinite number of points within any distance > 0...

Comment: You cannot really find all lat/long pairs; there are infinitely many of them. You can, however, define a geometric boundary in terms of lat/long pairs and then determine whether or not a given lat/long pair x,y falls within that boundary.

Comment: You can find them alright, you just can't list them in finite memory. But a mathematical representation of the resulting shape, or a test, is the next best thing. I don't see why this justifies a downvote.

Comment: I have a db table of lat and long values which are locations of lets say street lamps, given a lat long pair how could i find all those that are within a particular distance.

Comment: Using SQL Server 2008, by chance?

Comment: No, but I could do if it makes a difference? Using SQL Server 2005 with .net and Entity framework

Comment: How many points are there in the database?  If there are ten, a hundred, a thousand, then just compute the distance to each point in the database and filter out the ones that are too far away. If there are millions, billions, trillions of points in the database then this probably is not efficient enough; there are ways to organize a database to optimize for your search problem but they are a bit tricky.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the Haversine Formula (see @tdammers answer) to calculate a distance between each point (Lat, Long) in your table and the given point.  You will have to iterate over the entire collection in order to evaluate each point individually.

Or, if you are using SQL Server 2008, then geospatial support is built-in.  Each record would store the location as a geography type (possibly in addition to two discrete columns to hold Latitude and Longitude, if it's easier to have those values broken out), and then you can construct a simple SQL query:

```
DECLARE @Point geography = 'POINT(-83.12345 45.12345)' -- Note: Long Lat ordering required when using WKT

SELECT * 
FROM tblStreetLamps
WHERE location.STDistance(@point) < 1 * 1609.344  -- Note: 1 mile converted to meters
```

Another similar possibility is to bring the SQL Spatial types into your .NET application.  The redistributable is found here: http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=CEB4346F-657F-4D28-83F5-AAE0C5C83D52 (under Microsoft® System CLR Types for SQL Server® 2008 R2).

Then, the querying can be done via LINQ.  Note: This saves you from implementing the Haversine by yourself, otherwise the process of querying would be the same.

```
var yourLocation = SqlGeography.Point(Latitude, Longitude, 4326);

var query = from fac in FacilityList
            let distance = SqlGeography
                          .Point(fac.Lat, fac.Lon, 4326)
                          .STDistance(yourLocation)
                          .Value
            where distance < 1 * 1609.344
            orderby distance
            select fac;

return query.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: does it work with sql server 2008 (i mean linq query) ?

Answer (score 1):

The [haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula) gives you the distance (in meters; converting to miles is trivial) between two lat/lon points. From there, you can probably find the reverse...

Answer (score 1):

I'm a little late for answering this, but I came up with a trick years ago to do essentially the same for satellite fields of view.

There are two points on earth where you exactly know the latitude and longitude of every point a given distance from your location. Those points are the North and South poles. So let’s put the point you want at North pole. One nautical mile away is the circle of longitudes with latitude 90 degrees minus 1 minute, or 90 – 1/60 degrees = 89.9833 degrees North latitude, since 1 minute of arc = 1 nautical mile.

Now that you have the locus of longitudes one mile from the pole with latitude 89.9833, you essentially rotate the earth until the lat/long you want is where the pole used to be. This process is called “The Rotation of the Map Graticules”. The math for this is straight forward, once you’ve thought about the equations awhile. I have them buried somewhere, so I can’t get to the code easily, however the process, with the equations is in John Snyder’s book “Map Projections: A Working Manual”. You can get the pdf free at http://pubs.usgs.gov/pp/1395/report.pdf. The explanation is on pages 29 – 32.

Chuck Gantz

Answer (score 0):

some time ago I was solving a problem how to get POIs along the road. I made use of quadtree, that means dividing the whole area into cells and subcells recursively. Each POI belongs to only one cell. Having these cells you can easily do high level calculation on cell level and after that search only cells with intersection. It's more game development technique but can be used here as well. Here is something about it on Wiki:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadtree

Comment: Suppose you have a set of points P stored in a quad tree. Suppose you have a query point q and you wish to find the p in P closest to q. Suppose the correct p just happens to be on the west side of the line dividing the NW and NE quadtrees, and q just happens to be just on the east side of the line. How do you know to search a quad that q is *not* in to find p?

Comment: But it's not a million miles away from how Lucene implements spatial searches. It's just needs to be adapted, see http://www.mhaller.de/archives/156-Spatial-search-with-Lucene.html

Comment: A simple c# quadtree implementation here for reference: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/QuadTree.aspx)